# Error that allows me to compile and run the program normally

Tags: c#, runtime-error

I found quite an interesting error and it seems I'm not able to figure out what is happening.

The code that prompts the error is as follows:

```
tower = GetVariable<ITower>("TOWER", () => { return null });
```

GetVariable tries to find a string that matches the one introduced as the first parameter, if there is a match it will return the object stored for said string, otherwise it will return the object instatiated in the second parameter. I return a null parameter since, in the case of a class that implements ITower I should not be able to continue further ahead in the code, after retrieving this value, I check for nullity and throw an exception in the case tower is null.

tower can be any of three classes that implement the ITower interface, which manages any and all instruments used by the program to test the behaviour of a unit under test (UUT)

The error window prompts the following error:

> Cannot convert from lambda expression to type "Tools.Instruments.ITower" because it is not a delegate type

This would not be very important if this error prevented me from compiling or running the application, since I would have to fix this error firstly.

What has me worried is that I can compile normally and after compiling, it prompts the error window with the previous error, but finishes the build normally, I can run too the code without any problems, but ** in run-time this error is also shown** while I am running the code through the debugger.

This is not normal in my opinion and I want to know whether it's a bug in the code I am using (GetVariable is part of the company's framework, so I can't put the code here, just say that it retrieves an object when a given key exists in it, much like a Dictionary does) or there's something I am missing here and what implications this can have.

If the information supplied doesn't help at all I will try to post a piece of code regarding GetVariable to help you to help me in finding the source of this error, I am out of ideas.

Again, the code runs and behaves normally, but this error prompted during run-time has me worried about the actual behaviour of the code. Can this code be unsafe as to actually prompt a critical error that can reset the machine? I can't allow this to happen at all since my work involves testing devices and reseting the computer that controls the power supplies and other instruments is by no means something that should happen.

Comment: Can you prepare [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Can you try to cast your lambda expression to  `Func<Tools.Instruments.ITower>` or declare it the line before with a variable?

Comment: Doesn't `GetVariable<ITower>("TOWER", () => { return null })` accept as first argument the name and as second the object to get the value from? So `() => { return null }` would be no suitable object beeing `null`? If not Adding the head of `GetVariable` may help solving your problem.

Comment: I will edit as to give more information about what GetVariable does

Answer (score 0):

It seems I found the root of the problem, GetVariable has 2 overloads like the following:

```
public T GetVariable<T>(string key, T def)
{
    var variables = SequenceContext.Current.Variables;
    if (variables.ContainsKey(key))
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(variables[key], typeof(T));

    return def;
}

protected T GetVariable<T>(string key, Func<T> def)
{
    return SequenceContext.Current.GetVariable<T>(key, def);
}
```

even though the one that uses a Func is protected, I could use said overload in the code and it behaved like expected, thus prompting the error specified since a lambda expression could not be converted to type T

Modifying the declaration of said overload from protected to public fixes the error since now I can use a lambda expression to declare the default return value in case there is not a match for the specified string.

Comment: Why dont you just call the public one without using lambda and passing `null` as second argument? The one who has written the methods probably had a reason to make the second one protected. And if you pass a wrong key, you should be promted with the error again, I think.

Comment: if I return a null value with the first method, I get an exception that says "object must implement IConvertible", that's why I am using second